How can I import Tynker skins to my Nintendo Switch?
I want a protogen skin but all I have is a Switch and I don't know how to import that on Minecraft Bedrock.

Sadly, you can't.
The console doesn't allow importing custom files. There's no official way to do that.
Maybe with a jailbreak console...

WAIT. I know a work-around to get into google on switch. Maybe that’ll work.

@CarterLongfellow if you found a solution let us know!
